# Bug with persistent cookie text

Tags: magento2, theme, frontend

I'm currently testing a new Magento 2 shop, based on a Templatemonster theme and appear to have a bug with the persistent login welcome message at the top of the page.

It displays the following:

```
Welcome, Customer Name! <span><a href="http://shop2.domain.com/en/persistent/index/unsetCookie/" >Not you?</a></span>
```

If I inspect the source, here is the full html that is being outputted-

```
<div class="greet welcome" data-bind="scope: 'customer'">
            <span data-bind="text: customer().fullname ? $t('Welcome, %1!').replace('%1', customer().fullname) : 'Welcome, Customer Name! <span><a href=&quot;http://shop2.domain.com/en/persistent/index/unsetCookie/&quot; >Not you?</a></span>'">Welcome, Customer Name! &lt;span&gt;&lt;a href="http://shop2.domain.com/en/persistent/index/unsetCookie/" &gt;Not you?&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/span&gt;</span>
        </div>
```

Anyone know where I should look?

Comment: Have you asked the creator of the theme for support?

Comment: I'm also discussing it with them but so far have just been told where to edit the welcome message.  As the welcome message is being replaced by a different message from the persistent login module though that's not been a big help.. thought I'd post the question on here too in case anyone else recognised the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found in the end that it is the following line

```
<span data-bind="text: customer().fullname ? $t('Welcome, %1!').replace('%1', customer().fullname) : '<?=$block->escapeHtml($welcomeMessage) ?>'"></span>
```

in:  \app\design\frontend\TemplateMonster\framework\Magento_Theme\templates\html\header.phtml

But instead of the standard welcome message, the persistent login module is giving a message which includes an html link in the text which is being escaped.

For now, unless some one can suggest a better solution, I've replaced that line in header.phtml with the following which seems to work -

```
<span><? echo $welcomeMessage; ?></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is a bit late, but I think that I have found a fix.

Replace

```
<span data-bind="text: customer().fullname ? $t('Welcome, %1!').replace('%1', customer().fullname) : '<?=$block->escapeHtml($welcomeMessage) ?>'"></span>
```

with

```
<span data-bind="html: customer().fullname ? $t('Welcome, %1!').replace('%1', customer().fullname) : '<?=$block->escapeHtml($welcomeMessage) ?>'"></span>
```

So the only thing that you have to change is **text** into **html** inside the `data-bind`.

I am using this theme too and I have seen that it has lots of bugs that I am trying to solve. The interesting point here is that the creators did not tell you directly this solution, as it seems to be some kind of typo in the code.